# Wordpress shows admin's avatar after editing a comment

Tags: comments, updates, editor, avatar, gravatar

Recently I updated my wordpress to 4.2.1 and now I have a problem with editing people's comments. After editing them, the avatar picture of who edited the comment is shown instead of the avatar of the real man who wrote the comment. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Find all the functions "get_avatar" used in your theme folder.
Identify the wrong calls `echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' );`
or

`echo get_avatar($comment,48,'<path_to_url>' );`

If you find these,then change it to `echo get_avatar( $comment, 48 );` .
Hope this gonna help you :)

Comment: The problem is not with my theme. because even in /wp-admin/edit-comments.php page I face this issue. I had no problem before updating my wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. It was [WordPress Move Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/vb-wp-move-comments/) plug-in's issue and the problem solved by disabling this plugin. I'll say this problem to the developers today.